# save multiple plots (from ggplot2) using a for-loop by side-by-side

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I saved ggplot in for loop like this. I have total around 300 plots (`i = 1,,,300`). I would like to save the plots with with `pdf` file but save 4 plots in a page (2 by 2)  in the pdf file. If so, the output of `pdf` file should have 75 pages.

`for( i in 1:300){
plot_list[[i]] = ggplot(out, aes(basket_size_group_by2dol, pct_trips_w_item, colour=channel2)) + ylim(min00,max00) + 
    geom_point() 
}`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have generated a list of plots you can generate the pdf using the `ggsave` function fro the `ggplot2` package and the `marrangeGrob` function form the `gridExtra` package.  Here is a small example that generates eight plots and saves them, four to a page, in a two page pdf.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

plot_list <- vector("list", 8) 
plot_list[[1]] <- ggplot(mtcars) + aes(x = wt, y = mpg)   + geom_point() + ggtitle("This is plot 1")
plot_list[[2]] <- ggplot(mtcars) + aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)  + geom_point() + ggtitle("This is plot 2")
plot_list[[3]] <- ggplot(mtcars) + aes(x = disp, y = mpg) + geom_point() + ggtitle("This is plot 3")
plot_list[[4]] <- ggplot(mtcars) + aes(x = drat, y = mpg) + geom_point() + ggtitle("This is plot 4")
plot_list[[5]] <- ggplot(mtcars) + aes(x = drat, y = mpg) + geom_point() + ggtitle("This is plot 5")
plot_list[[6]] <- ggplot(mtcars) + aes(x = qsec, y = mpg) + geom_point() + ggtitle("This is plot 6")
plot_list[[7]] <- ggplot(mtcars) + aes(x = vs, y = mpg)   + geom_point() + ggtitle("This is plot 7")
plot_list[[8]] <- ggplot(mtcars) + aes(x = gear, y = mpg) + geom_point() + ggtitle("This is plot 8")


### Use your plot_list here:
glist <- lapply(plot_list, ggplotGrob)
ggsave("plots.pdf", marrangeGrob(glist, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Additionally, is there any way of reducing the scale such as scale = 0.8 or something like that?

Comment: I think by `scale = 0.8` you are looking to modify the spacing between the plots?  You can set the plot margins in ggplot via `ggplot2::theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2,2,2,2), "cm"))`, for example.  Try adding that to the plots, producing the pdf, and adjusting the `plot.margin` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the `cowplot` and `plot_grid()` function and append the grid with `ggplot2` objects. E.g. see: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_grid.html

**[EDIT]**:
Example code (tested code):

```
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=2*(1:10),z=(1:10)^2)
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=z)) + geom_point()
plot_grid(p1, p2, labels=c("A","B"))
```

the following logic may allow to extend the idea to a dynamic for-loop:

```
plotlist <- list(p1,p2)
plot_grid(plotlist=plotlist)
```

**[EDIT2]**:
Here is a small demo for using the split command. I generate a vector `x` (works with lists same way) from 1 to 12. Then I generate my factor `f` which defines the groups (same number, same group). using `split` returns 4 lists of `x` , grouped by the factor `f`.

```
x <- 1:12
f <- rep(seq(1,4),each=3)
split(x,f)
```

$`1`
[1] 1 2 3

$`2`
[1] 4 5 6

$`3`
[1] 7 8 9

$`4`
[1] 10 11 12

You may compare with this extra code to understand what happens:

```
f1 <- rep(seq(1,4), times=3)
split(x,f1)
```

$`1`
[1] 1 5 9

$`2`
[1]  2  6 10

$`3`
[1]  3  7 11

$`4`
[1]  4  8 12

Also you get the help pages for R functions by:

```
?split
?plot_grid
```

and even for packages

```
?cowplot
```

Comment: please see my edits, you can specify a `plotlist` argument to the plot_grid function. If you now (however ... e.g. using lapply) create a list of ggplot objects, you can forward the list to plot_grid

Comment: For your specific problem. You do the following: 1) create a plotlist of all plots, 2) `split()` the list into chunks of 4 plots each 3) run a plot_grid on each chunk using plotlist argument 5) to arrange in 2by2 you may use `ncol=2` argument